# Adding props on styled components getting opposite result

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, styled-components

I have created styled components and Im changing a text color by passing props.

```
          <Button variant = 'colour' type="submit" form="myForm" className="submit-btn">
            Submit
          </Button>
```

```
export const FindFormModal = styled(Modal)`

  .submit-btn {
    width: 35%;
    padding: 12px;
    color:${props => props.variant === 'colour'  ? 'blue' : 'green'}
    border-radius: 3px;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 0px 0 10px 0;
  }

`
```

In this if `variant === 'colour'`  then show `blue` but I'm getting `green`. If i do `variant !== 'colour'` then I get `blue`.

Isn't have to be working opposite?

Comment: Is there a reason to use a css class here? You're also missing a semi colon. What does your Modal css look like? It works as you intended for me if I replace Modal with a div and remove the class.

Comment: There are lot of classes above and for the submit button am customizing it. I'm pretty new to css and styled components and I cant replace Modal here. If i change it to div it wont work. It has something to do with react portals I guess. I don't know much about

Comment: Give my answer a try

Answer (score 1):

You don't usually want to be using className along with styled components.

```
export const FindFormModal = styled(Modal)`
    width: 35%;
    padding: 12px;
    color:${props => props.variant === 'colour'  ? 'blue' : 'green'};
    border-radius: 3px;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 0px 0 10px 0;
`

<Button variant = 'colour' type="submit" form="myForm">
    Submit
</Button>
```

Comment: why not good to use className with styeld components?

Comment: Part of the reason styled components is used, is so you don't need to add classes to your elements. This is the way it is intended to be used. https://styled-components.com/docs/basics